# Swift Code Error while creating option variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, compiler-errors

```
var option = [NSObject : AnyObject]?.self
option = [CIDetectorSmile = true, CIDetectorEyeBlink = true, CIDetectorImageOrientation : 6]
```

> Error: Expected ',' separator

```
var features = faceDetector.featuresInImage(sourceImage, options: option)
```

> Error: Cannot invoke 'featuresInImage' with an argument list of type ('CIImage, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?Type?)

How can I resolve that compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`featuresInImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIDetector/featuresInImage:options:) has the following signature:

```
func featuresInImage(_ image: CIImage, options options: [String : AnyObject]?) -> [CIFeature]
```

The `options` are of type `[String : AnyObject]?`. Yours is of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`.

**Solution:** use

```
var option : [String : AnyObject]? = [CIDetectorSmile : true, CIDetectorEyeBlink : true, CIDetectorImageOrientation : 6]
```

Since you actually supply always supply options, you can even remove the `?`.

*Further notes*

The `Expected ',' separator` is caused by your usage of `=` and `:` in the dictionary value declaration, always use `:`!

Comment: what about "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' " error?
What does that mean?

Comment: @Vivek was that previously there or is that occuring now? If it was previously there, it was the compiler getting confused to your usage of `:` and `=`